# How to add multiple rows in ngFor table dynamically in edit mode in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I have an ngFor table in which i can add a single row in edit mode, which has some select boxes in it.

I am able to edit, cancel and save the data into the database which is mysql.

The question is that i need to add more than one row dynamically in the table in edit mode and save them all in one go.
Actually it is a project for my office, so i can't share any code.
but i'm using

```
myArray.splice(0,0,newObject);
myArray = [...myArray]
```

to add a new row into the table.
How can i add multiple rows using the same having its individual cancel button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma620786626433166?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

You can work with a `FormArray` to do that. Basically, each row of your table will be an entry in your `FormArray`:

```html
<form [formGroup]="_form" novalidate>
    <table>
        <tbody formArrayName="data">
          <tr *ngFor="let array of _form.get('data').controls; index as i"
              [formGroupName]="i">
            <td>
              <input matInput 
                     formControlName="name" 
                     placeholder="Name" 
                     required>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input matInput 
                     formControlName="surname" 
                     placeholder="Surname" 
                     required>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select formControlName="gender">
                <option [ngValue]="null">GENDER</option>
                <option *ngFor="let g of _genders" [ngValue]="g">
                  {{g}}
                </option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button (click)="_removeRow(i)" type="button">
                Remove
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <button type="button" (click)="_addRow()">
                New Row
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Notice that the controls in form array are also `FormGroup`'s instead of simple controls. The overall `_form` can be declared as:

```js
this._form = this._formBuilder.group({
  data: this._formBuilder.array([])
});
```

And you can add a `FormGroup` to the `FormArray` by doing:

```js
const formArray: FormArray = this._form.get('data') as FormArray;

const form = this._fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  surname: ['', Validators.required],
  gender: [null, Validators.required]
});

formArray.push(form);
```

You can remove a row by removing it from the formArray:

```js
const formArray: FormArray = this._form.get('data') as FormArray;
formArray.removeAt(index);
```

Comment: will try this, and let you know

Comment: but any idea how will i abhe to handle select boxes, as fetching individual values of dynamically generated select box is an issue

Comment: I'll put a stackblitz demo together

Comment: That it is... with a demo. I used @angular/material in the demo, but with a native select control just to demonstrate that there's no special treatment with it. BTW, I wasn't sure if by "Select box" you were referring to a select control or to a checkbox control.

Comment: i was referring to a select control, but it is ok.. i'll look for a workaround with fetching values of multiple select control.